# How can I change ng-select's items with directive?

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I think I am missing something very basic, please forgive me for that but I really can't find the problem.

I just want to set ng-select's parameters (including items) with a directive. It's working on some static properties like clearAllText, but I can't use my directive to change items.

Here is sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-tests-share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked help from great developer friends and here is the solution

```
hostSelectComponent.ngOnChanges({
  items: {
    previousValue: [],
    currentValue: hostSelectComponent.items,
    firstChange: false,
    isFirstChange: () => false,
  }
});
```

And complete app link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-update-from-directive

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think what you want to is not possible.

**ng-select** uses a OnPush change detection strategy. so when you set  `[items]="currenciesData"` in the ng-select component, the only way to change the items is when currenciesData reference changes.  In your directive you tried to change the reference of `items`, which have no effect on `currenciesData`.

As `currenciesData` is a external variable to `ng-select`, there seems no way you can modify it in a directive inside `ng-select`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried to remove items on ng-select element and set it with directive firstly but it still gives same result. If it's not possible, I guess I should try something like mix ng-select and custom reactive form component.

Comment: Hi @Haijin, the problem is solved, please check the answer. Maybe it can help you either. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.